# Ender 3 Pro thermal runaway

Tags: creality-ender-3, thermal-runaway

From day one, I had issues with the bed unleveling all the time even if I hadn’t touched it.

After watching more videos I bought springs and I was having fantastic prints every time. There was no need for levelling between prints - it worked perfectly.

The day before yesterday I got an error warning `thermal runaway printer halted please reset` so I did as the printer said and again tried the print and 20-30 mins in the exact same issue. I watched more YouTube videos and replaced the motherboard with an SKR E3 V2.0 mini with Marlin firmware installed on to it.

After installing I went ahead and tried to test print (file on provided micro SD card) and 30 mins in I got a `thermal E1` so I went ahead and watched more YouTube videos which suggested that I connect my printer to my PC via a USB (provided) and download Pronterface. I followed the instruction of typing `M303 V5 200` into the command prompt and sent it to the printer which again halted the printer with `E1` error code. I went over to the printer and unplugged the USB and waited while the printer was off before plugged the USB back in.

After doing this I got a `TMC CONNECTION ERROR` message on the printer. I followed some Reddit/Github posts that said:

> Send command `M122` to the printer, this should work, which it did not.

As it stands at this moment this printer has gone from working perfectly to nothing at all.

Comment: Please clarify your question:. "nothing at all" doesn't sound like "thermal runaway."

Comment: It will print 1 or 2 layers then thermal runaway message comes up with a loud beeping noise

Comment: So you replaced the controller board and experience the same thermal runaway behavior. That implies that the board isn't the cause. You need to check the rest of the hardware. Loose/faulty thermistor or heater cables, fan shifting onto the hotend, etc.

Comment: I have corrected this issue by fully replacing the hot end and wiring (thermistor and heating cartridge)

Comment: I’m guessing you don’t know then